# Grease Pencil export to PSD layers?

Tags: rendering, grease-pencil, render-layers, layers

I am working at a studio that uses Photoshop as its primary storyboarding tool.

Is there a way to render / export Grease Pencil animation as a multi-layer PSD image sequence? Can GP object layers be separated into separate PSD or even TIFF layers?

I have experimented with exporting to "Open EXR Multilayer" but that only shows up as a black window in Photoshop. I've had better luck with "Open EXR" -- but, alas, no layers.

I would love to be able to use Blender at work in this way. It would be a real time-saver.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You can try: https://www.exr-io.com/ for your multilayer file. Also in the compositor if that's an option, you can add a file node and remove the actual name for the RGB beauty channel (leave it blank), that way photoshop should display that channel properly, at least.

Comment: Thank you! I will give that a try and check out the link. I had a suspicion that the answer may involve the compositor / nodes -- but I have ZERO experience with that aspect of Blender. Maybe it's time to learn it.